# Angular 6 - How to maintain the jwt session in each request?

Tags: node.js, angular6

I am using Angular 6 and NodeJS (API).

For authentication i am using JWT session token. While login i can authorize token and logged into homepage. But when using application continuously its not maintaining the session. Token expired 30 sec. Its not resetting the token for each request.

Using HttpInterceptor for sending token each request.

Angular code:

```
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

constructor(private router: Router) { }

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (req.headers.get('No-Auth') == "True")
        return next.handle(req.clone());

    if (localStorage.getItem('userToken') != null) {
        const clonedreq = req.clone({
            headers: req.headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('userToken'))
        });
        return next.handle(clonedreq)
            .pipe(
                tap(event => {
                    if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                      const elapsed = Date.now();
                      console.log(`Request for ${req.urlWithParams} took ${elapsed} ms.`);
                    }
                  }, error => {
                    console.error('NICE ERROR', error)
                  })
            );
    }
    else {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
    }
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your backend needs to handle this, either return a new token every request, or increase the time that it takes to expire

Comment: For each request should we need to send new jwt token back to front end?

Comment: if the time you put is too short, you gonna have to renew the token, that is sending a new one, or you can increase the time it takes to expire.

Comment: Got what you wanted ?